# Flat Shipping rate for per 3 product in magento?

Tags: shipping

I am trying to create a shipping rule in magento. In this rule I need some functionality like **$50 per 3 products** will add as shipping rule. If someone added **4 items to 6 items in cart**, then the shipping charges should **$100** (**$50 for first 3 pair** of items and other **$50 for remain items**).

But i am stuck and didn't found any extension or solution for this.

Comment: if 7 item then shipping cost 150???

Comment: yes...exactly what i want...

Comment: magento version ?

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 1**

Follow [this tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/14/magento-create-custom-shipping-method/) to create custom shipping method

in config.xml

```
<default>
        <carriers>
            <customshipping>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>customshipping/carrier_customshipping</model>
                <name>Custom Shipping</name>
                <title>Custom  Shipping </title>
                <description>50 Shipping cost per 3 item</description>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </customshipping>
        </carriers>
</default>
```

create shipping model class

```
<?php  
    class Stackexchange_Customshipping_Model_Carrier_Customshipping     
        extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
        implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
    {  
        protected $_code = 'customshipping';  

        /** 
        * Collect rates for this shipping method based on information in $request 
        * 
        * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data 
        * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result 
        */  
        public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){  
            $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

             if ($request->getAllItems()) {
                $count=0;
                foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    $count+=$item->getQty();
                }
                $count=ceil($count/3);
                $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');  
                $method->setCarrier($this->_code);  
                $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                $method->setMethod($this->_code);  
                $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
                $method->setPrice($count*50);
                $method->setCost($count*50);
                $result->append($method);  
            }
            else
            {
                $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
                $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
                $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
                $error->setErrorMessage('Shipping Method is not available');
                $result->append($error);
            }
            return $result;
        }  

        /**
         * Get allowed shipping methods
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getAllowedMethods()
        {
            return array($this->_code=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
        }
    }
```

Created [module for you](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_7hBzRP1KDmUmYxN0pXb3JGNDg/view?usp=sharing).